# How can I use this ggplot and use my input to change the variable name for y?

Tags: r, ggplot2, flexdashboard

For some reasons the three inputs works fine, they are used to filter the data frame. But the last input to change between variable names does not work. Can anyone find the error or the solution. My code is follows:

---

### title: "Janus Heilsuefling"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
```

### Inputs {.sidebar}

```
bara_fyrsta <- read.csv("bara_fyrsta.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")
vanir <- read.csv("fyrir_thor.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")

vanir$aldursflokkur <- cut(vanir$aldur, c(65,70,75, 80, 120), right = F)
bara_fyrsta$aldursflokkur <- cut(bara_fyrsta$aldur, c(65,70,75, 80, 120), right = F)
levels(bara_fyrsta$aldursflokkur) <- c("65-70 ára","70-75 ára", "75-80 ára","80 ára og eldri")
levels(vanir$aldursflokkur) <- c("65-70 ára","70-75 ára", "75-80 ára","80 ára og eldri")

bara_fyrsta$Kyn <- factor(bara_fyrsta$Kyn)
vanir$Kyn <- factor(vanir$Kyn)

listi_sveitarfelog <- unique(bara_fyrsta$sveitarfelag)
listi_aldursflokkar  <- unique(bara_fyrsta$aldursflokkur)
breytulisti <- names(bara_fyrsta)


selectInput(inputId = "sveitarfelag",
                      label = "Veldu sveitarfélag",
                      choices = listi_sveitarfelog)

selectInput(inputId = "aldursflokkur",
                      label = "Veldu Aldursflokk",
                      choices = listi_aldursflokkar)


Kynjalisti<-c("Karl", "Kona")
selectInput(inputId = "Kyn",
                      label = "Veldu Kyn",
                      choices = Kynjalisti)

breytulisti <- c("MMa","Dagleg_Hreyfing_Medaltal", "Life_Quality","HaStyBadar","Stóll_30s","BMI")

selectInput(inputId = "talnabreyta",
                      label = "Hvaða breytu viltu skoða?",
                      choices = breytulisti)






output$mynd_boxplot <- renderPlot({bara_fyrsta %>% 
      filter(sveitarfelag == input$sveitarfelag) %>%
      filter(Kyn == input$Kyn)%>%
      ggplot(aes(x=aldursflokkur, y=input$talnabreyta)) +geom_boxplot()})
```

### Column {data-width=450}

#### Dreifing á vövðamassa fólks í upphafi

```
plotOutput("mynd_boxplot")
```

#### Leiðrétt meðaltöl fyrir mælingarnar 5

```
vanir <- vanir %>% arrange(RN,Mæling) %>% mutate(m=factor(Mæling))
fit1 <- lmer(MMa ~ m + aldursflokkur + Kyn + (1|RN),data=vanir)
ema <-emmeans(fit1,pairwise~m)
dema <- data.frame(ema)

medaltol = 
  plot(ema,horizontal=F)
  
ggplotly(medaltol)
```

### Column {data-width=450}

#### Upphafsstaða út frá kyni og aldri

```
mynd = ggplot(bara_fyrsta, aes(x = aldur,y = MMa, color = Kyn)) +
geom_point() + geom_smooth(se = F)
ggplotly(mynd)
```

#### Endurtekningar mælingar einstaklinga

```
idkendur <-unique(vanir$RN)
gagnasett <- filter(vanir, RN==idkendur[2])
linurit = ggplot(gagnasett, aes(x = Mæling, y = MMa, color = Kyn)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
ggplotly(linurit)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to understand your code/question, as a lot of it is in Faroese. However, your main issue with the plot has to do with `input$talnabreyta` being a string, which cannot be passed as a variable name in `ggplot` as you do. You need to treat it either as a string in the proper way (1) or use it as a symbol (2).

I.e.

Change:

(0) `ggplot(aes(x=aldursflokkur, y=input$talnabreyta))`

To:

(1) `ggplot(aes(x=x, y=.data[[input$talnabreyta]]))` or

(2) `ggplot(aes(x=x, y=!!ensym(talnabreyta)))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It really helped me a lot!

Comment: Please accept the answer if that was the case. Have a good day.